# How to calculate the standard error of an odds ratio from the standard error of two logits?

Tags: standard-error, logit, odds-ratio

For example, given two logits and their standard errors:

Logit = -3.1435, SE = 1.6847
Logit = -2.7581, SE = 0.9081

I can calculate the odds ratio to be exp(-2.7581 - -3.1435) = 1.47, but is there a way to calculate the standard error of this odds ratio using the standard error of the two logits?

Comment: Just a thought - I'm not confident since this is a little beyond me at the moment - is it possible that the standard error of the log(OR) based on the standard errors of the logits would be similar to estimating the variance of a difference? (e.g. something like var(ln(OR)) = sqrt[(1.6847^2)+(0.9081^2)])?